# node v0.5.0 pre Socket.IO crashes on connection (independent of transport)

Tags: node.js, crash, connect, socket.io

When I try to connect to socket.io it crashes with the following error message:

```
Initializing client with transport "websocket"
node: ../src/node.cc:1212: ssize_t node::DecodeWrite(char*, size_t, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, node::encoding): Assertion `b[1] == 0' failed.
Aborted
```

This happens when I try to start up the node chat example. (server.js file in the example folder).
The installed socket.io version is the current version installed by using npm install socket.io.

Does anyone know what the reason for this crashing might be? How can fix it?

**Fixed -- Turns out I was running node v0.5.0 pre which apparently is not (yet) compatible with socket.io.**

Comment: could you update your question containing something like v0.5.0-pre because some other people also have problems of crashing build and also accept your answer by first answering it yourself ;)??

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out I was running node v0.5.0 pre which apparently is not (yet) compatible with socket.io