# when this error come how to solve this error 

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, socket.io

I am developing an app in node.js socke.io redis mysql , so this error arrvied some time don't know when it arrived and how to find where this error come , how to solve this error .?

```
node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: ETIMEDOUT, Connection timed out
    at Socket._onConnect (net.js:600:18)
    at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:186:12)**strong text**
```

Comment: I think we need way more information. Is that the complete stack trace? What version of node.js are you using? Which modules do you have installed and which version? It could be a socket.io bug by the way? I would try and get the most simple form to crash node.js and post the code over here.

Comment: @Alfred yeah it is the complete stack trace , and m using node 0.5.0-pre , modules of mysql ,node_redis  , socket.io ,simpledb are there .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I read somewhere on stackoverflow or someplace that socket.io is not yet completely comptatible with `0.5.0-pre`. Could you try the latest official build `v0.4.8` instead and report back?

---

That's correct :). I read it on stackoverflow.com and found the link to it also: [node v0.5.0 pre Socket.IO crashes on connection (independent of transport)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329881/socket-io-crashes-on-connection-independent-of-transport)

Comment: It's probably best to use 0.4.8 but it's a connection time out issue which is probably not an error just the developer forgot to handle the time out situation

Comment: The other topic tells us it has crashes because of 0.5.0-pre build. I also believe he debugging enabled(when compiling node.js) which could also help us track down this crash

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a socket error emitting an "error" event, but not finding any listeners for "error" events.  In this case, node converts the event into an exception.

So the simple thing to check is make sure that you are listening for errors on all of your connections.

There is a tricky bug right now where some sockets emit errors before, or possibly after the user code can be listening for errors.  I see this a lot when doing HTTPS.  If you are hitting this uncatchable error situation, there's not much you can do about this besides changing node to not convert those socket errors into exceptions.  If you can come up with a reliable way to reproduce this issue, it'll get fixed much more quickly.